# error finding in QT

Tags: qt, debugging, error-handling

In QT-creator I am getting the following error:

> ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range", file c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 359

My problem is that it does not specify which QVector is out of range... Even when I run in debug mode I cannot find the location of the error. Is there a way to easily find the error? The code is quite huge and the error only pops up every once in a while so it would be a lot of work to check every qVector I use separately.

Comment: If you run in debug mode, the debugger should break when the error happens, then you should be able to trace back the error.

Comment: @Laurent: It does break down, but it only gives me a vague description of the error, not the possition

Comment: @divanov: debug means I use the play button with the bug instead of the one without the bug :)

Comment: @Frank Further up the stack trace you will see which of your methods led to `QVector::operator[]` being called.

Comment: debugging means CONFIG+=debug, and starting the executable in a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using Qt Creator, there is a "Stack" window which shows the function calls which led to the point where your program stopped:

[image: Picture of the Stack Window]

In that window, double click the first file which you know is your own file, in that screenshot it is main.cpp in line 5. The file will open and a yellow arrow will be shown. The line which caused the assertion is the line above that yellow arrow (That arrow actually points to the next statement which would have been executed)

Comment: When compiling with MinGW, Q_ASSERT doesn't allow you to break into the debugger. I've had this problem before. Even if you start in the debugger, it would still terminate the application.

Comment: Indeed I use qt creator. This is the way that I found previous errors, but with this one the stack is empty. Nothing is shown in this screen.

Comment: That does not work when some Q_ASSERT fails.  SEGFAULTs and other crashes, yes, but not Q_ASSERTs... Debugging these asserts is a pain.